# Webscraping HTML data using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to **scrape** some data using R from the following website to obtain a data frame of

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)

ebsite1
website1 %>%
  html_nodes(".miscTxt a") %>%
  html_text() -> countries_list

countries_list
```

I have a hit a roadblock as I am unsure of how to assign the continents to the countries and need help on that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script scraping the continents and countries to a data frame.

- Iterate through the `li` nodes of the source code
- Extract the continent & country of each `li` using the `helper` function
- Store the data in a data frame

```
# Helper function
helper <- function(li)
  c(continent=gsub('.*href="https://www\\.worldatlas\\.com/webimage/countrys/([A-z .]*?)/.*\\.htm".*', 
                   '\\1', li, perl = TRUE),
    country=rvest::html_text(li))

# Scrape the data
u <- 'https://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm'
continents <- c('africa', 'asia', 'europe', 'namerica', 'oceania', 'samerica')
m <- t(vapply(rvest::html_nodes(xml2::read_html(u), 'li'), helper, FUN.VALUE = character(2)))

# Make a clean data frame
df <- data.frame(m)
df <- df[df$continent %in% continents,]
rownames(df) <- 1:dim(df)[[1]]

# A glimpse
head(df)
#   continent  country
# 1    africa  Algeria
# 2    africa   Angola
# 3    africa    Benin
# 4    africa Botswana
# 5    africa  Burkina
# 6    africa  Burundi

tail(df)
#     continent   country
# 189  samerica    Guyana
# 190  samerica  Paraguay
# 191  samerica      Peru
# 192  samerica  Suriname
# 193  samerica   Uruguay
# 194  samerica Venezuela
```